# Jquery mask not working on a field which is disabled and then enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#ClientID").mask("999-999999999");
    }
}
```

Now this mask works fine in the Textbox when the textbox is enabled. Sometimes though when the page loads we have this field as disabled, and there is unlock checkbox, which enables that field. The problem is when we enable this field, then the mask does not appear.

There is a chance that something else other than the disable/enable might be the problem but I haven't figure it out yet.

Any suggestions?

Comment: which jquery mask plugin are you using?

Comment: @yetanothercoder: I am not sure, it say masked-input-plugin from digitalbush. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All is fine when I test the below code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ClientID").mask("999-999999999");
});
```

The test box is cleared only when at the time of disabling if the input doesn't match the mask, then the input gets vanished

Masked input version used: 1.2.2
Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/ULgyW/).

On an unrelated side note dont use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(function ($) {

    });
});
```

Because `jQuery(function ($)` is the [shortcut](http://www.coldfusioning.com/index.cfm/2009/10/26/jQuery-Document-Ready-Shortcut) for `$(document).ready(function ()`